# Ruby dynamic object creation

Tags: ruby, object

Okay so I am trying to create an object for each found email domain in a text file. So far I have the matching system working and now have ran into a problem creating the objects on the fly. Here is what I got so far.

```
# domain = emails domain name (e.g. 'example.com')
# Agency = class for domain

        if (domain + "Object").nil? == false 
            domain = Agency.new(domain + "Object")
            @agencyList << domain
            domain.addEmail(match)
            puts "false"
        elsif (domain + "Object").nil? == true 
            domain.addEmail(match)
            puts "true"
           end
        end
     end
```

So basically I want to check if the email domain already has an object created for it. If it doesn't, create an object using the domain name and send the matched up with the object method addEmail. If it does send the match to object method addEmail. I don't want to use hashes because I want the matches in separate arrays.

I have tried many things and I think I am in over my head. This is my first ruby script. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `(domain + "Object").nil?` will never be true.

Comment: Yup, thats my main issue. I need a way to check if the object is created.

Comment: as pointed out by [xdazz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/762073/xdazz) `domain + "Object"` will return an object (usually a String if `domain` is a `String` as I suppose). Alternatively it my raise `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'domain'` if `domain` has not been assigned. I suggest you post the code of the whole method and a call sequence that fails, otherwise we will keep guessing what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: There are several things about the question that need to be clarified.  Let's suppose `domain => 'example.com'`, so `domain + "Object" => "example.comObject"` and you are adding that string to `@agencyList`.  Correct?  By `if (domain + "Object").nil? == false` are you asking if `@agencyList` contains a string such as `"example.comObject"`?  In `domain.addEmail(match)` what is `match`?  It is not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to check whether the object is in your agency list. Something like:

```
if @agencyList.any? {|agency| agency.domain == domain }
  agency = Agency.new(domain)
  @agencyList << domain
  agency.addEmail(match)
  puts "false"
else
  domain.addEmail(match)
  puts "true"
end
```